# Unable to access image from database with knockout binding

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, knockout.js, asp.net-identity

This is my code to bind an image with the help of knockout view model:

```html
<img data-bind="attr: { src: PostedByAvatar }">
<p><a data-bind="text: PostedByName"></a>: 
<span data-bind=" html: Message"></span></p>
```

This is my `GetPosts` methods for fetching posts with the help of knockout view model to show onto view page:

```
public JsonResult GetPosts()
{
    var ret = (from post in db.Posts.ToList()
               orderby post.PostedDate descending
               select new
               {
                   Message = post.Message,
                   PostedBy = post.PostedBy,
                   PostedByName = post.ApplicationUser.UserName,
                   PostedByAvatar = db.Files.SingleOrDefault(s => s.ApplicationUserId == post.PostedBy),
                   PostedDate = post.PostedDate,
                   PostId = post.PostId,
            }).AsEnumerable();
    return Json(ret, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

and this is my knockout view model to load the existing posts from the database:

```
function viewModel() {
    var self = this;
    self.posts = ko.observableArray();
    self.newMessage = ko.observable();
    self.error = ko.observable();
    self.loadPosts = function () {
        // to load existing posts
        $.ajax({
            url: postApiUrl1,
            datatype: "json",
            contentType: "application/json",
            cache: false,
            type: 'Get'
        })
        .done(function (data) {
            var mappedPosts = $.map(data, function (item) { return new Post(item); });
            self.posts(mappedPosts);
        })
        .fail(function () {
            error('unable to load posts');
        });
    }
```

This is my `applicationUser` class. I am using ASP.NET Identity for authentication and authorization.

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser<int, CustomUserLogin, CustomUserRole, CustomUserClaim>
{
     public ApplicationUser()
     {
         this.Posts = new HashSet<Post>();
         this.Files = new HashSet<File>();
     }
     public virtual ICollection<File> Files { get; set; }
     public virtual ICollection<Post> Posts { get; set; }
```

And this is my `File` class which save the userprofile pic in database and it has  `ApplicationUserId` foreign key pointing to applicationuser class.

```
public class File
{
     [Key]
     public int FileId { get; set; }
     [StringLength(255)]
     public string FileName { get; set; }
     [StringLength(100)]
     public string ContentType { get; set; }
     public byte[] Content { get; set; }
     public FileType FileType { get; set; }
     public int ApplicationUserId { get; set; }
     public virtual ApplicationUser ApplicationUser { get; set; }
}
```

I am facing problem in binding image correctly to knockout view model so that it fetches image correctly from database. If anyone has any suggestions, it would be really helpful.

For Reference, you can have a look at [this article](http://techbrij.com/facebook-wall-posts-comments-knockout-aspnet-webapi); 
I am just using normal controller in place of Web API controller and ASP.NET identity in place of simple membership, that's it.

Comment: You seem to return array from the server. Is your `<img>` (as well as the other relevant elements) scoped within a `foreach`?

Comment: Also, your Linq query is extremely inefficient. The `ToList()` and `AsEnumerable()` can be omitted.

Comment: @haim770 yuppp <ul id="msgHolder" data-bind="foreach: posts">
    <li class="postHolder">
        <img data-bind="attr: { src: PostedByAvatar }"> 
        <p><a data-bind="text: PostedByName"></a>: <span data-bind=" html: Message"></span></p> it is like this

Comment: @haim770 hello sir, i have provided the article which i was following. u will get whole idea what i am doing

Comment: For a start, your `attr: { src: PostedByAvatar }` assumes that `PostedByAvatar` is indeed a string (Url pointing to some image), but the code in your controller implies that you're actually returning the entire `File` object. You need to construct a Url from your `File`.

Comment: And most importantly, you don't specify what is your actual problem. What is your expected result and what is the current result?

Comment: In the original article you're referring to, it explicitly constructs a url from the `File`. See `PostedByAvatar = imgFolder +(String.IsNullOrEmpty(usr.AvatarExt) ? defaultAvatar : post.PostedBy + "." + post.UserProfile.AvatarExt)`

Comment: @haim770 okk sir many many thanks but how will the url be constructed

Comment: The directory where your images are stored + "/" + `file.FileName` may work. But that's really something you need to be able to ask yourself.

Comment: @haim770 should i change PostedByAvatar from string return type to HttpPostedFileBase return type?? would that work.I have to return image from database i dont know how to modify it to make it a url of string type

Comment: `attr: { src: PostedByAvatar  }` is meant to work with a url, returning the actual image bytes from the database will require you to use base64 encoding. But, you don't seem to want to return the actual bytes because you're already having a `FileName` and that means the bytes are already stored somewhere. Just check *where* was the file stored (for example, if it was stored in `http://www.yourwebsite.com/Images` folder, the `PostedByAvatar` needs to contain the string `http://www.yourwebsite.com/Images/FileName` or `/Images/FileName`.

Comment: @haim770 okk okk i got the idea what i have to let me try if failed i will let u know thnk u for guidance

Comment: @haim770 i have tried something like this but not working ---- [attherate]if (Model.Files.Any(f => f.FileType == App.Models.FileType.Avatar)) { 
       <img src="~/File?id=@Model.Files.First(f => f.FileType == App.Models.FileType.Avatar).FileId" alt="avatar" /> 
        } plzz sir come in chat if possible